# Cant compile/install plugin on Windows

Tags: eclipse, go

I've been trying to install this, I installed go, and also git, but when I follow the instructions to write:

```
go get github.com/anaminus/rbxplugin
go install github.com/anaminus/rbxplugin
```

into CMD I just get errors.

Is there any way someone can compile this for me into an exe or something so I can use it?

It wont compile with eclipse either. I have tried this on git, and also set my Gitroot and project location, it still wont install it.

This is the [github project](http://github.com/anaminus/rbxplugin). I am trying to compile :

Comment: "…I just get errors". This isn't helpful. Please edit your question and add the *exact* error messages you receive.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The tags you chose are not appropriate for this question. Please review [What are tags, and how should I use them?](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) The "source" tag specifically shouts "DON'T USE THIS TAG".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not for requests-to-compile an application.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are seeing are because the code is broken.

```
src\github.com\anaminus\rbxplugin\rbxplugin.go:54: cannot use client (type *http.Client) as type *rbxweb.Client in argument to asset.Upload
src\github.com\anaminus\rbxplugin\rbxplugin.go:54: assignment count mismatch: 3 = 2
src\github.com\anaminus\rbxplugin\rbxplugin.go:70: undefined: rbxweb.DoRawPost
src\github.com\anaminus\rbxplugin\rbxplugin.go:97: cannot use client (type *http.Client) as type *rbxweb.Client in argument to asset.Upload
src\github.com\anaminus\rbxplugin\rbxplugin.go:97: assignment count mismatch: 3 = 2
src\github.com\anaminus\rbxplugin\rbxplugin.go:111: undefined: rbxweb.Login
```

You will either need to get the project owner to fix these compilation errors or fork the project and fix them yourself.

Not every project on github is guaranteed to actually work.